# GetUpperBound() and GetLowerBound() function for array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Can anyone please tell what does the two functions do? They take an integer argument which is told to be dimension. But how does the value of this integer changes the output?

Below is an example which I ran.

```
int[, ,] intMyArr = {{{ 7, 1, 3, 4 }, { 2, 9, 6, 5 } }, { { 7, 1, 3, 4 }, { 2, 9, 6, 5 }}};
Console.WriteLine(intMyArr.GetUpperBound(0));       // Output is 1
Console.WriteLine(intMyArr.GetUpperBound(1));       // Output is 1
Console.WriteLine(intMyArr.GetUpperBound(2));       // Output is 3

Console.WriteLine(intMyArr.GetLowerBound(0));       // Output is 0
Console.WriteLine(intMyArr.GetLowerBound(1));       // Output is 0
Console.WriteLine(intMyArr.GetLowerBound(2));       // Output is 0
```

Any idea why GetLowerBound() is always returning 0? If this always returns 0 then why do we
need to call this method?

Comment: An array can have more than one dimension. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Patashu nothing is written about these functions in this link. Can you please tell how the functions work?

Comment: Google, first result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx

Comment: Some examples: http://dev.fyicenter.com/dot-NET-Tutorial-for-Beginners/121_Getupperbound_and_getlowerbound_.html

Comment: Back in the VB6 days it was common to have a lower bound of 1, now days in order to be CLR complient arrays must have a lower bound of 0.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5dkx9yy(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 23):

May be some examples make the topic clear for you

We use `GetUpperBound()` to find out the *upper bound* of an array for *given dimension*, 
like that:

```
  int[,,] A = new int[7, 9, 11];
  // Returns 6: 0th dimension has 7 items, and so upper bound is 7 - 1 = 6;
  int upper0 = A.GetUpperBound(0); 
  // Returns 8: 0th dimension has 7 items, 1st - 9 and so upper bound is 9 - 1 = 8;
  int upper1 = A.GetUpperBound(1); 
  // Returns 10: 0th dimension has 7 items, 1st - 9, 2nd - 11 and so upper bound is 11 - 1 = 10;
  int upper2 = A.GetUpperBound(2);
```

usually, `GetLowerBound()` returns **0**, since arrays are *zero-based* by default, 
but in some rare cases they are not:

```
  // A is [17..21] array: 5 items starting from 17
  Array A = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 5 }, new int[] { 17 });
  // Returns 17
  int lower = A.GetLowerBound(0); 
  // Returns 21
  int upper = A.GetUpperBound(0);
```

Typical loop using `GetLowerBound` and `GetUpperBound` is

```
  int[] A = ...

  for(int i = A.GetLowerBound(0); i <= A.GetUpperBound(0); ++i) {
    int item = A[i];
    ...
  }

  // ... or multidimension

  int[,,] A = ...;

  for (int i = A.GetLowerBound(0); i <= A.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
    for (int j = A.GetLowerBound(1); j <= A.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
      for (int k = A.GetLowerBound(2); k <= A.GetUpperBound(2); ++k) {
        int item = A[i, j, k];
        ...
      }
```

Comment: Hi regarding the comments above, do you mean the changes i have highlighted and surrounded by ***** below, rather than what's above? Slightly confusing for a noob like me // Returns 6: 0th dimension has 7 items, and so upper bound is 7 - 1 = 6;
  int upper0 = A.GetUpperBound(0); 
  // Returns 8: ****1st***** dimension has 7 items, 1st - 9 and so upper bound is 9 - 1 = 8;
  int upper1 = A.GetUpperBound(1); 
  // Returns 10: *****2nd***** dimension has 7 items, 1st - 9, 2nd - 11 and so upper bound is 11 - 1 = 10;

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: when we declare array like `int[] x = int[3];` it means that `x` has *3* items: `x[0], x[1], x[2]`, so as you can see the *last item* (which is x`[2]`) has index `2 == 3 - 1` (`Length - 1`); in general
case `int[] x = int[n]` we'll have `x.Length == n` and `x.GetUpperBound(0) == n - 1`

Answer (score 7):

The integer parameter to `GetUpper/LowerBound()` specifies the dimension.

Some examples:

```
// One-dimensional array
var oneD = new object[5];
Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0 Lower bound: {0}", oneD.GetLowerBound(0)) // Outputs "Dimension 0 Lower bound: 0"
Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0 Upper bound: {0}", oneD.GetUpperBound(0)) // Outputs "Dimension 0 Upper bound: 4"

// Two-dimensional array
var twoD = new object[5,10];
Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0 Lower bound: {0}", twoD.GetLowerBound(0)) // Outputs "Lower bound: 0"
Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0 Upper bound: {0}", twoD.GetUpperBound(0)) // Outputs "Upper bound: 4"
Console.WriteLine("Dimension 1 Lower bound: {0}", twoD.GetLowerBound(1)) // Outputs "Lower bound: 0"
Console.WriteLine("Dimension 1 Upper bound: {0}", twoD.GetUpperBound(1)) // Outputs "Upper bound: 9"
```

Whilst arrays defined within C# have lower bound = 0 and upper bound = length - 1, arrays from other sources (e.g. COM interop) can have different bounds, so those working with Excel interop for example will be familiar with arrays that have lower bound = 1, upper bound = length.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please tell what does the two functions do?

It is written in their MSDN pages. They gets the index of the *first / last* element of the specified dimension in the array. Take a look [`Array.GetUpperBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx) and [`Array.GetLowerBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx)

> They take an integer argument which is told to be dimension.

Yes, as Patashu *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358139/getupperbound-and-getlowerbound-function-for-array#comment25189099_17358139)*, arrays can have [multidimension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> Any idea why GetLowerBound() is always returning 0? If this always
>   returns 0 then why do we need to call this method?

<strike>In an array, every dimension can have their specific lower and uppor bounds. So, this methods can create different results for each dimension of array.</strike>

> Note that, although most arrays in the .NET Framework are zero-based
>   (**that is, the** `GetLowerBound` **method returns zero for each
>   dimension of an array**), the .NET Framework does support arrays that
>   are not zero-based. Such arrays can be created with the
>   [`CreateInstance(Type, Int32\[\], Int32\[\])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx) method, and can also
>   be returned from unmanaged code.

Check out;

- [Workaround: Arrays with non-zero lower bounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbfaq/archive/2004/04/20/116660.aspx)
- [How to: Specify a Zero Lower Bound on an Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5dkx9yy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It's also possible to get non-zero lower bounded arrays from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, i.e. Data = (object[,])range.Value2; returns a one-based array to C#