# What is the rationale behind GetUpperBound() in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I'm learning C# and am from a Java + Python + D background. I'm accustomed to iterating over an array from zero to its upper bound, through code such as the following (in Java):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

But C#, for multidimensional arrays, I can't get the length of an individual dimension-- .Length on a multidimensional array gets the total number of available elements. Jagged arrays might be an exception, but they aren't what I'm working with. To get a specific dimension, I've had to use .GetUpperBound(...) , which returns the length of the array minus one.

Before I jump to any conclusions, is there a reason for it to be doing this, and cutting against a trend in C-style programming languages stretching back to at least 1972? Is there an easy way to get that value other than .GetUpperBound(...) - 1? It feels very messy to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a comparable example of accessing a *multidimensional* array in Java?

Comment: I can see some overlap, but that does not address the full scope of my question-- is it possible to quickly get the length of a dimension?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but  can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893297/iterate-multi-dimensional-array-with-nested-foreach-statement

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's more or less the same; in Java, all arrays may be jagged arrays. Therefore, it would be something like array.length for the first dimension, array[0].length for the second, array[0][0].length for the third, etc.

Comment: @DragandDrop That looks like what I'm looking for, thank you! Could you write it as an answer, instead of a comment, so that I can accept it?

Comment: If this is what you are looking for a simple duplicate flag will be good. Duplicate are not a bad things. Asking the same question multiple time with new word will help people finding it in the future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358139/getupperbound-and-getlowerbound-function-for-array/17358481#17358481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for multidimensional arrays, I can't get the length of an individual dimension-- .Length on a multidimensional array gets the total number of available elements

That makes sense since multi-dimensional arrays are actually just a contiguous block of memory. Returning `Length` as the actual total length of the array seems to make sense.

`GetUpperBound` and `GetLowerBound` are convenient if you want to know the actual dimensions of that array, or know if the array starts at `1` instead of `0` for example. In that case iterating over items `0..Length-1` doesn't cut it.